# Search for specific file content of text documents, in all documents on my site and on subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search-results, sub-site, sharepoint-search

I would like to search all documents on my site. I want to search in the documents, i.e. in the text of word documents etc.
How can I do this? Do I have to set it somewhere? Unfortunately it does not work yet.

For testing purposes I have put a document with a certain string into my document library:
[image: document with teststring]

I would like to be able to enter this string in the search box and then the corresponding document should be displayed to me.
I can remember that this once worked - I've seen/read this before that this function is supported. Anything else would be very sad for sharepoint, it's there for document management...

[image: no search results]

As you can see on the screenshot the search does not work

How can I implement my requirement?

Comment: It could be that `#` is treated as a special character, try to replace it with `\#` or try with a more straight forward test token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until the document is crawled, search should do this for recognized file types like (doc, docx) out of the box. Note that does not include PDF. Or you can re-index the library in which you have this word file,

**Re-index a document library or a list**

1. On the site, go to the list or library that you want to re-index.
2. In the ribbon, click the Library tab or the List tab.
3. In the Library ribbon, choose Library Settings. Or, in the List ribbon, choose List Settings.
4. On the Settings page, under General Settings, choose Advanced settings.
5. Scroll down to Reindex Document Library or Reindex List, and click the button. The content will be re-indexed during the next scheduled crawl.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How long does it take to re-index?

Comment: Have a look at this post regarding re-index, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224210/sharepoint-online-search-crawling